# Read property from POM into java code

Tags: java, maven, webdriver, pom.xml

Let's say I have two maven profiles for running projects web tests:
 1. first deploys to CI tomcat instance with say `http://ci.blahblah.com:8080` address and then tests are run
 2. second profile for developers who can deploy to embedded tomcat using tomcat:run. So their address for web tests would be like `http://localhost:8080`

Now I created both profiles in pom file and in each of them in section `<properties>` I also created `<base.url>` property with different address for each profile.

Is there any way how I can now read these values into my java class where I launch web-tests using Webdriver so I could have sth like `driver.get("address from pom <base.url>")` ??

It simply allows developers to run web tests locally before commiting his/hers code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).  For instance:

First change your code so that it pulls the address from the properties file.  Many ways to do this (reading the properties file directly, using spring propertyplaceholderconfigurer, etc)

```
String address = getAddressFromPropertiesFileOrInjectedFromSpringOrWherever();
driver.get(address)
```

Next create the properties file that will store this information, most likely in src/main/resources.  Ensure that the value of your property uses the same name as your maven variable:

```
webAddres=${base.url}
```

Ensure that filtering is setup in your profile as per the link above.

Comment: Could you describe how to achieve that using spring inject?

Comment: This blog entry is probably a good start: http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-example/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, Try to call this system :

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:evaluate -Dexpression=base.url
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an **Environmental Entry** in your **web.xml** and parse it in your web application.

Example:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>projectStage</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>Development</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>

  ...
</web-app>
```

**Webapp code**

```
String projectStage = "";

try {
  Context context = new InitialContext();
  Context environment = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");
  projectStage = (String) environment.lookup("projectStage");
} catch (NamingException ex) {
  //
}
```